# build yocto image with apache2

Tags: apache, embedded-linux, bitbake

I have been using QorIQ-SDK-V1.5 to build image for p1020rdb. However, there's no apache in the image which is what I need. But I also noticed that there's recipe in meta-webserver for apache, and I could build it separately by "bitbake -b" option. So my question is: How do I add the apache objects to image at build time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add apache2 object to image at building time.

1. clone meta webserver from git

   ```
   $ git clone git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded
   ```
2. copy meta webserver your yocto home

   ```
   $ cp -R meta-openembedded/meta-webserver {your-yocto-home}
   ```
3. edit bblayers.conf

   ```
   $ cd {your-build-home}
   $ vi conf/bblayers.conf

   BBLAYERS ?= " \
   {your-yocto-home}/meta \
   {your-yocto-home}/meta-poky \
   {your-yocto-home}/meta-yocto-bsp \
   {your-yocto-home}/meta-webserver \
   "
   ```
4. edit local.conf and add this line

   ```
   $ vi conf/local.conf

   IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " apache2"
   ```
5. bitbake core-image-minimal

   ```
   $ bitbake core-image-minimal
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can find layers and recipes for Open Embedded in this [link](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-webserver/). Clone the layer directory or add the recipe if the layer is already present in your Yocto.

meta-webserver layer can be found [meta-webserver layer](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-webserver/). Apache recipe from [Apache recipe](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/5976/)

After adding a recipe to your poky dir, you need to **append** the package to install it your image.

Comment: could you please show the code snippets that you talk about above? and the relevant files that each code snippet goes into ? Thank you